# Yahoo email client: <ins> html tag

Tags: html, email, tags, yahoo

Apparently, when sending an email containing the `<ins>` tag to a Yahoo client, the tag gets removed, including its inline CSS. This is weird, as the `<del>` tag stays alright.
Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to replace `<ins>` with `<span style="text-decoration:underline">` in your email code.

### Background

`<ins>` is typically used in conjunction with `<del>` to show edits to text.

This code...

```
<p>The best color is<del> blue</del><ins> red</ins></p>
```

renders like this...

> The best color is <del>blue</del> r̲e̲d̲

This code renders the same way...

```
<p>The best color is<del> blue</del><span style="text-decoration:underline"> red</span></p>
```